# How to write this postgresql dynamic query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a custom spatial function and its working with this parameters (coordinates):

```
SELECT get_nearest_station (-80.364565, 26.070670);
```

Now, I want to update column "SOURCE" for all rows in a table 'employees_wgs' with this function.
Coordinates are in columns X and Y for each record so I have to replace real coordinates with value from those columns.

How to write this query ? Is this need to be dynamic sql or else ?

Thanks

Comment: I would consider ***not*** to store the functionally dependent value redundantly. Create a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) instead. If you need to optimize performance, consider a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update employees_wgs
  set source = get_nearest_station(x,y);
commit;
```

Comment: that was fast! Thanks. I will try immidiately